# defining multiple services on Dockerfile with single CMD

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Say I have the commands:

`rails server`

and

`bundle exec something:default`

I understand my Dockerfile can only have 1 CMD line so is it ok to do:

`CMD ["sh", "-c", "rail server && bundle exec something:default"]`

As it's just those 2 commands, I don't want to COPY a script.sh then use that (hoping for a simple 1 line way).

Is there a best practice I should be aware of when running 2 services in one container?

Comment: Best practice is to *not* run two services in one container.

Answer (score 4):

It is best practice to run a single service in each container, but it is not always practical. I run CMD ["sh", "-c", "/usr/sbin/crond && php-fpm"] so I can use the laravel scheduler. So in answer to the question, yes the above does work.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
rail server
bundle exec something:default
```

then add a COPY to your Dockerfile

```
COPY mycmd.sh /app
```

/app is your destination

and finally execute your script in a CMD step

CMD ["mycmd.sh"]

Comment: As I only have 2 lines - could I instead just that place that in a line like: `CMD ["sh", "rail server && bundle exec something:default"]`

Answer (score 0):

Docker container is running while main process inside it is running. So if you want to run two services inside docker container, one of them has to be run in a background mode.

So, `CMD` layer should be the following:

```
CMD ( rail server & ) && bundle exec something:default
```

Answer (score 0):

The rule of thumb is to have "*one process per container*". The purpose of the rule is to decouple applications into multiple containers. Take a look here [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#avoid-installing-unnecessary-packages) - *Each container should have only one concern*

So if you are running two *Rails* applications it's probably better to create two containers.

The way you run the two services has a couple of issues. First, the processes are not supervised so the container cannot manage them correctly. Use a process manager like `supervisord`, if this is a concern. See [Run multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/). Second, the services are started by a shell so the signals will not reach your application.